# Get subchild value from an xml with jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, google-maps

I working with Google maps v3, and I want to get the short name of the country where a marker was geocoded. But I can't get the `short_name` subchild from the google maps' xml.
The returned xml like this: http://code.google.com/intl/hu/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#XML

I would need the "`US`" from this example. This is my function:

```
function codeLatLng(latlng) {
  if (geocoder) {
  geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      var str = '';
      jq.each(results, function(){
        str += this.formatted_address+'|';
      });
      str = str.split('|');
      jq('#address').text(str[0]);
    }
  });
  }
}
```

But I would need the "`short_name`" subchild under the 7th `address_component`.
Thanks!

Sorry for my English...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you solved your problem? If not try this function:

```
function codeLatLng(latlng){
    if (geocoder) {
        geocoder.geocode({
            'location': latlng
        }, function(results, status){
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var str = '';
                var i = 0, len = results.length, loop = true;
                while (i < len && loop) {
                    for (var j = 0, len2 = results[i].address_components.length; j < len2; j++) {
                        if (results[i].address_components[j].types[0] == 'country') {
                            str = results[i].address_components[j].short_name;
                            loop = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                jq('#address').text(str);
            }
        });
    }
}
```